# inequality test of two columns from same dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, scala-spark

in scala spark we can filter if column A value is not equal to column B or same dataframe as
`df.filter(col("A")=!=col("B"))`
How we can do this same in Pyspark ?

I have tried differemt options like
`df.filter(~(df["A"] == df["B"]))` and `!=` operator but got errors

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this snippet:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 1)], "id: int, val: int")
df.show()
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.filter(col("id") != col("val")).show()
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```